# Upgrade to Laravel 5.6 from 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I have one little problem after updating my Laravel 5.5 project to 5.6.

All packages is was successful updated.

But one package is still have issue.

Console result:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- The requested package fideloper/proxy ~4.0 is satisfiable by fideloper/proxy[4.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

But i already define 4.0 version in my composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

And add 2 line in composer.json

```
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
```

And after make autoload command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This error is appear:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
```

> @php artisan package:discover

```
In trustedproxy.php line 66:                                        
Undefined class constant 'HEADER_CLIENT_IP'  
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Are there any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does any other package require a conflicting version of `fideloper/proxy`. There are commands like `composer why fideloper/proxy` that can help figure out conflicts like this.

Comment: It looks like you're using the `config/trustedproxy.php` config file. That points to not using the built in Laravel implementation of the trusted proxies package, so I closed this as a duplicate of another question that addresses this situation.